# Select individual Android device over TCP/IP in ADB

Tags: android, ip, virtual-machine, adb, android-x86

I need to be able to direct commands to a single device when multiple devices are connected in ADB via the `adb connect <ip>` command. Running `adb devices` gives me the following output:

```
List of devices attached
192.168.1.72:5555   device
192.168.1.71:5555   device
```

running `adb logcat` with only one device connected works fine for both of them, but using the documented `adb -s 192.168.1.72:5555 logcat` (both with and without the port) won't work:

```
$ adb -s 192.168.1.72:5555 logcat
- waiting for device -
```

How can I select an individual android device on the network to run a command via TCP/IP? Please note I am using 2 VM instance of Android x86 to test this (and that's how I will eventually use the tool I am developing)

Comment: I have tried the same as above, but It works just fine. I'm **not** able to reproduce the same issue. 

You should verify if you are connected to the network properly, use `ping` from your devices to the host machine.